# Using MAX to compute MAX value in a subquery column

Tags: sql, oracle, dense-rank

What I am trying to do: I have a table, "band_style" with schema (band_id, style).
One band_id may occur multiple times, listed with different styles.
I want ALL rows of band_id, NUM (where NUM is the number of different styles a band has) for the band ids with the SECOND MOST number of styles.

I have spent hours on this query- almost nothing seems to be working.

This is how far I got.  The table (data) successfully computes all bands with styles less than the maximum value of band styles.  Now, I need ALL rows that have the Max NUM for the resulting table. This will give me bands with the second most number of styles.

However, this final result seems to be ignoring the MAX function and just returning the table (data) as is.  Can someone please provide some insight/working method? I have over 20 attempts of this query with this being the closest.

Using SQL*PLUS on Oracle

```
WITH data AS (
SELECT band_id, COUNT(*) AS NUM FROM band_style GROUP BY band_id HAVING COUNT(*) < 
(SELECT MAX(c) FROM
(SELECT COUNT(band_id) AS c
FROM band_style
GROUP BY band_id)))
SELECT data.band_id, data.NUM FROM data
INNER JOIN ( SELECT band_id m, MAX(NUM) n 
             FROM data GROUP BY band_id
           ) t
   ON t.m = data.band_id 
     AND t.n = data.NUM;
```

Comment: How should ties be handled? What if, for example, three band_id are tied for the most distinct styles? Also, why are you counting band_id ANYWHERE? And you mentioned DISTINCT styles but you make no attempt to count (distinct something), why not?

Comment: If 3 bands are tied for most distinct styles, they are all the maximum and we don't want to consider them.  We just want second most styles.  It's assumed a band_id wont be listed as having the same style twice. @mathguy

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Something like this... based on a Comment under your post, you are looking for DENSE_RANK()

```
select band_id
from   ( select   band_id, dense_rank() over (order by count(style) desc) as drk
         from     band_style
         group by band_id
       )
where  drk = 2;
```

Comment: yes this works- I get the correct result! Is there any way of displaying count(style) next to the band ID? thank you

Comment: @rubyquartz: You can simply add `count(*) as cnt` (or any other aggregate function) to the inline view.

Comment: @rubyquartz - as dnoeth said, you can add `count(*) as cnt` to the subquery `select` clause, and then add `cnt` to the `select` clause of the main query.

Answer (score 1):

I would use a windowing function (RANK() in this case) - which is great for find the 'n' ranked thing in a set.

```
SELECT DISTINCT bs.band_id
FROM band_style bs
WHERE EXISTS (
    SELECT NULL
    FROM (
        SELECT 
            bs2.band_id, 
            bs2.num, 
            RANK() OVER (ORDER BY bs2.num) AS numrank
        FROM ( 
            SELECT bs1.band_id, COUNT(*) as num
            FROM band_style bs1
            GROUP BY bs1.band_id ) bs2 ) bs3 
        WHERE bs.band_id = bs3.band_id 
        AND bs3.numrank = 2 )
```